# Activestorage fixtures attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In rails tests. I have a basic model with only activestorage:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

I'm trying to make it's fixture, but having no luck with (I do have an image there):

```
# users.yml
one:
  avatar: <%= File.open Rails.root.join('test', 'files', 'image.png').to_s %>
```

How do I properly attach an avatar file through fixtures?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is far easier than anybody is making it out to be.  I don't mean to demean anybody, as it took me some time to figure this out based on these answers.  I'm going to use the same data model to make it easy.

User has one attached "avatar".  Let's say you have this users fixture:

```
# users.yml
fred:
  name: Fred
```

Here's all you need to do:

```
% mkdir test/fixtures/active_storage
```

Now, you just put "attachments.yml" and "blobs.yml" in that directory.  The "attachment" record will reference the blob as well as the user (note that the `name` entry is the name of the `has_one_attached` field):

```
# active_storage/attachments.yml
freds_picture:
  name: avatar
  record: fred (User)
  blob: freds_picture_blob
```

and

```
# active_storage/blobs.yml
freds_picture_blob:
  key: aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zmyw13A
  filename: fred.jpg
  content_type: image/jpeg
  metadata: '{"identified":true,"analyzed":true}'
  byte_size: 1000
  checksum: fdUivZUf74Y6pjAiemuvlg==
  service_name: local
```

The `key` is generated like this in code:

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.generate_unique_secure_token
```

You can run that in the console to get a key for the above fixture.

Now, that will "work" to have an attached picture.  If you need the actual file to be there, first look in config/storage.yml to see what path the files are stored in.  By default, it's "tmp/storage".  The file above will be stored here:

```
tmp/storage/aa/bb/aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zmyw13A
```

To calculate the checksum, see here:

[How is the checksum calculated in the blobs table for rails ActiveStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657619/how-is-the-checksum-calculated-in-the-blobs-table-for-rails-activestorage)

```
md5_checksum = Digest::MD5.file('tmp/storage/aa/bb/aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zmyw13A').base64digest
```

It would be possible to fill in the file size and checksum using erb in the fixture:

```
  byte_size: <%= File.size('tmp/storage/aa/bb/aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zmyw13A') %>
  checksum: <%= Digest::MD5.file('tmp/storage/aa/bb/aabbWNGW1VrxZ8Eu4zmyw13A').base64digest %>
```

Note that you have to copy the file into the storage directory first.
The storage root directory for the test environment is `tmp/storage/` by default, with the remaining path constructed from the first four characters of the `key` (i.e. `tmp/storage/aa/bb`).

Comment: How do you know that the file will be stored in `aa/bb`? What about if you have two files?

Comment: @Vadim, note that the directory `aa/bb` is based on the first four characters of the key.  You can have as many files as you want - just add more records.

Comment: Worth noting, that `service_name: %local%`, where %local% is the key from `config/storage.yml` must be present in `blobs.yml` in order the above mentioned method work.

Comment: @ArturBeljajev This is due to the recent update to active storage.  Thanks for pointing it out and I will update the answer.

Comment: As it was stated above, that solution fully works only if the real file exists under the configured save path. And given `tmp/` path is considered ephemeral (and usually git-ignored), I couldn't find any reliable way to ensure that such Active Storage testing emulation works properly.

Comment: @ArturBeljajev Change the path in config/storage.yml for "test".  Note that if the file is removed you'll have to handle that.

Comment: @MichaelChaney It is set to the default value of `Rails.root.join("tmp/storage")`. I assume it _will_ be removed, hence the name of the directory (`tmp`). Other than that, the open question for me are other instances than my local dev - CI, staging for example. Currently it seems the only way to handle that is to manually copy it and wait until it gets removed and then repeat the steps. Manual copying seems daunting if you have many instances where it's needed.

Comment: @MichaelChaney In fact, I have the following that runs after each test: `FileUtils.rm_rf(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'storage'))`, so it seems the above mentioned solution doesn't cover such case.

Comment: @ArturBeljajev Yeah, so set it to something not temp.  I typically just copy the files in and erase the directory when done.  I haven't done this with parallel tests yet, so there needs to be a way to handle the buildup/teardown per thread.  Since you seem to be interested in this, why not tackle it and update my answer?  I maintain a few answers like this that are meant to be canonical correct answers to popular problems in the rails world that aren't adequately addressed by documentation.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: @MichaelChaney thanks for this answer! I've made a PR to Rails partially based on it: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41543

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexGhiculescu ! Just added an answer with your updated guides

Comment: In Rails 6.0.4.1 I needed to to remove ```service_name``` from the ```blobs.yml``` because it was throwing a ```table "active_storage_blobs" has no columns named "service_name"``` error.

Comment: Note that if the model `has_many_attached`, you need to use the plural name in the `name:` field (in attachments.yml).

Answer (score 17):

Nowdays (rails 7), seems like the proper way according to the [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_storage_overview.html#testing) is to:

```
# config/storage.yml

test_fixtures:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage_fixtures") %>
```

```
# active_storage/users.yml
david:
  name: David
```

```
# active_storage/attachments.yml
david_avatar:
  name: avatar
  record: david (User)
  blob: david_avatar_blob
```

```
# active_storage/blobs.yml

david_avatar_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: "david.png", service_name: "test_fixtures" %>
```

Comment: This is an edge guide and will apply to rails 6.2 when it is released. Currently, in the latest 6.1.4.1 this doesn't work because `ActiveStorage::FixtureSet` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 14):

Lets say you have a test for the model user, the default `UserTest#test_the_truth`

`rails test test/models/user_test.rb`

I suppose you are getting an error
`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`
during the test, because of an error in your path,
you must add `'fixtures'`, it should be like:

```
# users.yml
one:
  name: 'Jim Kirk'
  avatar: <%= File.open Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'image.png').to_s %>
```

but now you should have this error: `ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "avatar".`

That's correct, because ActiveStorage uses two tables to work: `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs`.

---

So, you need to remove avatar column from `users.yml` and add two new files:

(**Disclaimer** See also comments below: "no need create own models, so instead of `ActiveStorageAttachment` you could use original `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and place fixture under active_storage folder" and refer also to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835955/5239030)

```
# active_storage_attachments.yml
one:
  name: 'avatar'
  record_type: 'User'
  record_id: 1
  blob_id: 1
```

and

```
# active_storage_blobs.yml
one:
  id: 1
  key: '12345678'
  filename: 'file.png'
  content_type: 'image/png'
  metadata: nil
  byte_size: 2000
  checksum: "123456789012345678901234"
```

Also, in `App/models`, add, **even if not required for the ActiveStorage to work**.

```
# active_storage_attachment.rb
class ActiveStorageAttachment < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and

```
# active_storage_blob.rb
class ActiveStorageBlob < ApplicationRecord
end
```

---

Then the `UserTest#test_the_truth` succeed.

But better **get rid of** `active_storage_attachment.rb` and `active_storage_blob.rb` and follow another way to test.

For testing if the attachment is working, **better test the controller**, for example adding this code in `test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @controller = UsersController.new
  end
  test "create user with avatar" do
    user_name = 'fake_name'
    avatar_image = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'avatar.png'),'image/png')
    post :create, params: {user: {name: user_name, avatar: avatar_image}}
  end
end
```

Check the folder `tmp/storage`, should be empty.

Launch the test with: `rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb`

It should succeed, then if you check again in `tmp/storage`, you should find some folders and files generated by the test.

**Edit after comments:**
If you need to test the callbacks on `User` model, then this should work:

```
# rails test test/models/user_test.rb

require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should have avatar attached" do
    u = User.new
    u.name = 'Jim Kirk'
    file = Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'image.png')
    u.avatar.attach(io: File.open(file), filename: 'image.png') # attach the avatar, remove this if it is done with the callback
    assert u.valid?
    assert u.avatar.attached? # checks if the avatar is attached
  end
end
```

I don't know your callback, but I hope this gives you some hint.

Comment: The thing is that I have an avatar validation for the model (it's required), and I don't want to attach it before every test (that's my workaround now). This is why I want to have them in fixtures.

Comment: The `User` model does not contains any informations about the attachment, the methods to retrieve it is generated by `has_one_attached` and the relation to the `User` is in the `active_storage_attachment table`. If you want to test the validation, can you provide that code?

Comment: It's not validated per se, but it attaches an avatar `after_validate on: :create` if not present, so, when a record is saved it always has an avatar, that is what I need in fixtures. I wouldn't mind having to create active_storage_attachments and blobs yml files, as long as I get this behaviour

Comment: @joseramonc, I edited adding test on user model, but I don't know if that exactly what you require.

Comment: I'd like that my user fixture has the avatar already attached when fixtures load, without need to do anything else

Comment: no need create own models, so instead of `ActiveStorageAttachment` you could use original `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and place fixture under active_storage folder

Comment: @iGian Please update your answer taking Igor's comment above into account.  Creating a model called `ActiveStorageAttachment` is wrong and may lead to other issues.  The actual model is `ActiveStorage::Attachment`, and that means a subdirectory for the fixture.  Please see my answer as well.

Comment: @MichaelChaney, thanks. Just added a disclaimer, since I'm not working on it and cannot test.

Comment: `u.avatar.attach(io: File.open(file), filename: 'image.png')` could be simplified to `attach(fixture_file_upload('image.webp'))` (`test/fixtures/files/product_image.webp` should exist, of cource).

Answer (score 11):

There's a lost comment by IS04 on the only answer that I just want to expand on.

I got stuck trying to do this for sometime and following iGian's answer did work for me. However my team reviewed my PR and asked why I was introducing new models so closely named to ActiveStorage's own models (i.e. `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and `ActiveStorage::Blob`).

It then occurred to me that all I needed to do was move the fixture from `active_storage_attachments.yml` to `active_storage/attachments.yml`.

The other part I had to figure out with extra research was how to use these fixtures with the automatically generated ids. Which I did so using `ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify` like this:

```
attachment_identifier:
  name: "attachment_name"
  record_type: "MyRecordClass"
  record_id: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:my_record_identifier) %>
  blob_id: <%= ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify(:blob) %>
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @Alex Ghiculescu for opening that PR to Rails which pointed me to "how Active Storage's test suite does it".
Unfortunately that code doesn't seem to be in 6.1 branch but they have an [ActiveStorage::FixtureSet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b038bb27a6162184faef3af6e1c676a893651d9f/activestorage/lib/active_storage/fixture_set.rb#L63)

In the meantime you could add this to your `test_helper.rb` (or however you'd like to organize your code:

```
class ActiveStorage::Blob
  def self.fixture(filename:, **attributes)
    blob = new(
      filename: filename,
      key: generate_unique_secure_token
    )
    io = Rails.root.join("test/fixtures/files/#{filename}").open
    blob.unfurl(io)
    blob.assign_attributes(attributes)
    blob.upload_without_unfurling(io)

    blob.attributes.transform_values { |values| values.is_a?(Hash) ? values.to_json : values }.compact.to_json
  end
end
```

Now you can add your `freds-picture.jpg` into `test/fixtures/files` and your fixture files like this:
`test/fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml`

```
freds_picture:
  name: picture
  record: fred (User)
  blob: freds_picture_blob
```

and `test/fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml`

```
freds_picture_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::Blob.fixture(
  filename: "freds-picture.jpg"
) %>
```

Hope that makes sense and once `ActiveStorage::FixtureSet` is in your Rails version you can remove the `self.fixture` method and replace `ActiveStorage::Blob.fixture` with `ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob` in your fixture yaml files.

Definitely works for me, loading a view that renders the fixture in system tests properly renders the image.