# How to create fixtures for models in Rails 5.2 that uses ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures, rails-activestorage

I am trying to write system tests in rails 5.2 for a resource that uses ActiveStorage, but I am unable to figure out how to setup a fixture that has an attachement...

Comment: Please provide the important/failing parts of your code. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453596/activestorage-fixtures-attachments), take a look.