# Attach Active Storage file to fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, fixtures, rails-activestorage

The documentation only show the way to attach a file to model (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects).

How about fixtures?

With `has_one_attached :file` in my model I tried the keys `file` and `file_attachments` but it doesn't work.

Do I have to create fixtures files for `ActiveStorage::Attachment` and/or `ActiveStorage::Blob` explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activestorage fixtures attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453596/activestorage-fixtures-attachments)

Answer (score 2):

In my testing, I've found that I have to attach using `fixture_file_upload`. Here are 2 examples in RSpec, but I believe the `fixture_file_upload` method should work in minitest as well. The key is to include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` at the top (unless you are using minitest, then I think it's available without include).

Attachment files are saved in: spec/fixturs/files/filename.gif

Model spec for attachment

```
require 'rails_helper'
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

RSpec.describe Whatever, type: :model do
  it 'is valid/invalid depending on file presence' do
    file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files', 'parrot.gif'), 'image/gif')

    expect(SomeClass.new(an_attribute: 'something', file: file)).to be_valid

    expect(SomeClass.new(an_attribute: 'something').to be_invalid
  end
end
```

Request spec

```
require 'rails_helper'
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

RSpec.describe "whatever", type: :request do
  file = fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files', 'parrot.gif'), 'image/gif')

  describe 'POST on whatever controller' do
    it 'saves the record when a file is attached' do
      expect{
        post whatever_path, params: { params: { file: file } }
      }.to change { WhateverModel.count }.by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough but I'm talking about attaching file in the YAML fixture file, not in the test.

Comment: It looks like it might be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453596/activestorage-fixtures-attachments Though I agree with this answer's conclusion, there are easier ways to test than putting it in the YAML using either `.attach` or `fixture_file_upload`