# Attach file Fixtures Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to attach a image in a fixure model following [this guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#file-attachment-fixtures), but all my tests are failing due the following error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::FixtureSet
test/fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml:1:in `get_binding'
```

I couldn't find anyone who have unintializer the ActiveStorage::FixtureSet

my blob fixture

```
cafe_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob( 
  filename: "cafe.jpg", 
) %>
soda_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob( 
  filename: "soda.jpg", 
) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue, and it looks like this method won't be released until Rails 6.2 (going to an earlier tag for [ActiveStorage::FixtureSet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/948e9d74e31bb25b67e60ba1cdc59edebb2fb640/activestorage/lib/active_storage/fixture_set.rb) in source shows the file doesn't exist in 6.1) and the only reference for this shows up in the edge guides, not the released guides.

I worked around this by manually specifying the fields required for ActiveStorage:

```
avatar_blob:
  key: '12345'
  filename: 'hot_dog.png'
  content_type: 'image/png'
  byte_size: 27172
  service_name: 'amazon'
  checksum: 'NzJmNGZkYTI4ODk5M2QxMTAzZTI3ZTgxMTM5MGIyYWY='
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835955/13758023), but the file location based on the generated token wasn't working, so the only difference I have to do was put a files in fixtures/files and use as base in blobs byte_size and checksum, like that:

in fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml

```
cafe_picture_blob:
  key: scxrex8xx73inir3c6216mrmowv0
  filename: cafe.jpg
  content_type: image/jpeg
  metadata: '{"identified":true,"analyzed":true}'
  byte_size: <%= File.size(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'cafe.jpg')) %>
  checksum: <%= Digest::MD5.file(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'cafe.jpg')).base64digest %>
```

in fixtures/active_storage:

```
cafe_picture:
  name: photos
  record: coffee (Item)
  blob: cafe_picture_blob
```

and in fixtures/files a jpg img of a coffee