# Create Active Storage image variant fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Creating test fixtures for Active Storage image attachments is laborious but possible:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835955/312681

This is great if you serve the original image in your tests, but in our case we use [variants](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html) to serve an optimised version.

I want to create test fixtures for the image **variant** not the original file, so that the variant is already present and not created by the first request for it. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So I got tripped up on this as well for a few hours, thinking that the issue was a function of minitest not correctly stubbing the activesupport attachment. However, after further investigation, I realized that the issue stemmed from the fact that I had not set up my fixtures correctly.

One key thing that helped me realize that testing the variants was a symptom of the fact that my blobs were not attaching was that when I ran `[model].[attachment].attached?`, it would return false.

The following SO post set me on the path to freedom: [Rails 7 ActiveStorage file attachment fixture does not like to attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74972196/rails-7-activestorage-file-attachment-fixture-does-not-like-to-attachment)

In my case, I was not setting up my attachments.yml correctly. As a result, `Blob#variants` was being called on a `nil` value and the tests ended up failing. Just to rehash what the linked SO post says, when setting up your attachments.yml, the following configurations must be true:

1. Name **MUST** match the how the attachment is called in the model
2. Record **MUST** match an existing model fixture
3. Blob **MUST** match an existing blob fixture

Once my attachments.yml file was correctly configured, calls to `Blob#variant` passed without a hitch.