# Rails 7 ActiveStorage file attachment fixture does not like to attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, rails-activestorage

Been trying to setup an ActiveStorage fixture to test my Rails 7 model using Minitest. I'm following steps in [File attachment fixtures](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) and [Adding attachments to fixtures](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#adding-attachments-to-fixtures).

I can tell that the fixture is being loaded into `ActiveStorage::Attachment` correctly:

```
(ruby) ActiveStorage::Attachment.all
[#<ActiveStorage::Attachment:0x00007ff16aa74f28 id: 93947105, name: "file", record_type: "Trades File", record_id: 824316784, blob_id: 821228354, created_at: Sat, 31 Dec 2022 21:39:50.514686000 UTC +00:00>]

(ruby) ActiveStorage::Attachment.first.filename
#<ActiveStorage::Filename:0x00007ff16656a0e0 @filename="tw_trades.csv">
```

However, when I try to access the attachment from the model, I receive `nil` values:

```
(ruby) TradesFile.first.file.filename
nil
(ruby) TradesFile.first.file.attached?
false
```

I can also confirm that the attachment refers to the correct model instance:
[image]

Here is my config:

`test/fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml`:

```
tw_file:
  name: file
  record: tw (Trades File)
  blob: tw_file_blob
```

`test/fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml`:

```
tw_file_blob:  <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: "tw_trades.csv", service_name: 'test_fixtures' %>
```

`test/fixtures/trades_files.yml`

```
tw:
  account: tw_account
  imported_at: 2022-12-22 11:32:49
```

`app/models/tw.rb`

```
class TradesFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_one_attached :file
...
end
```

## Update

One issue *may* be that my model is named `TradesFile` but the `record` field for `tw_file` in the `attachments.yml` is set to `Trades File` (with a space).

I removed the space so the record type matches the model name. However, I noticed that the `record_id` in the attachment no longer matches the id of the `TradesFile`:

[image]

Also calling `ActiveStorage::Attachment.first.record` returns `nil`, so it seems the attachment is linking to some record that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Success! Yes turned out the issue was the space in the `record` field in the `attachments.yml`.

For future readers, the `record` field in `attachments.yml` must *exactly* match the model name with the attachment.

So if you have:

```
# app/models/trades_file.rb
class TradesFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_one_attached :file
  ...
end
```

Then the `record` field must be:

```
# test/fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml
tw_file:
  name: file
  record: tw (TradesFile)
  blob: tw_file_blob
```