# Rails Minitest: ActiveStorage NoMethodError: undefined method `download'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I've got below model with ActiveStorage:

```
class PortfolioReport < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :pdf_upload

  validates :pdf_upload, content_type: 'application/pdf'
end
```

Now I want to test if ActiveStorage works well. I defined below fixtures:

```
# fixtures/active_storage/attachments.yml
pdf_upload:
  name: pdf_upload
  record: current (PortfolioReport)
  blob: pdf_upload
```

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453596/activestorage-fixtures-attachments/55835955#55835955) but the file location based on the generated token wasn't working (unsuccessfully tried to generate checksum - `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`). So I've put the sample pdf file into `fixtures/files/sample.pdf`. I ended up with below blob file:

```
# fixtures/active_storage/blobs.yml
pdf_upload_blob:
  key: 1234
  filename: sample.pdf
  content_type: application/pdf
  service_name: local
  byte_size: <%= File.size(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'sample.pdf')) %>
  checksum: <%= Digest::MD5.file(Rails.root.join('test', 'fixtures', 'files', 'sample.pdf')).base64digest %>
```

To test if it works I've got below minitest model:

```
class PortfolioReportTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'pdf attached' do
    pdf = portfolio_reports(:current).pdf_upload

    assert pdf.attached?
    assert_not_nil pdf.download
    assert_equal 374, pdf.byte_size
  end
end
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Error:
PortfolioReportTest#test_pdf_attached:
NoMethodError: undefined method `download' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:0x00007fd5c5b87890>
    test/models/portfolio_report_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:PortfolioReportTest>'
```

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in the Ruby Guide? https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#testing

Also, what happens when you try to access a file you upload directly in a test rather than through a fixture?  That way you may isolate whether it is a configuration problem or a fixture problem (I assume it is working in dev, so my money is on it being a fixture problem).

Comment: @DrewJohnston I did so, but I read that the method described in RailsGuides will be available in Rails 6.2. My application uses 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You have a `many` relationship.

If you expect to have only one attachment use `has_one_attached :pdf_upload`. If you want multiple files I'd suggest to use a plural name for the association: `has_many_attached :pdf_uploads`.

Then, if you use a `many` relationship, you have to tell ruby which file you want to download:

```rb
  test 'pdf attached' do
    uploads = portfolio_reports(:current).pdf_uploads

    assert uploads.attached?

    pdf = uploads.first
    assert_not_nil pdf.download
    assert_equal 374, pdf.byte_size
  end
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting an error: `PortfolioReportTest#test_pdf_attached:
ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError: ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError`

Comment: I would suggest yo check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453596/activestorage-fixtures-attachments#50667526 your comment is a different question now